# SQL Server - XML Load Issue

Tags: sql-server, xml-parsing, sqlxml

'Hi, i am trying to create automated XML load into SQL and initially I need to create the table with right data set. Ultimately i am trying to get Serial Number, IP Address and Timezone with all count values for "From to "to" time stamp Here is how my XML looks like:

```
<response xmlns="http://www.test.com/sensor-api/v2">
  <sensor-time timezone="America/New_York">2017-07-18T15:45:03-04:00</sensor-time>
  <status>
    <code>OK</code>
  </status>
  <sensor-info>
    <serial-number>Q8:80:39:60:9Z:F2</serial-number>
    <ip-address>192.167.130.18</ip-address>
    <name>Test</name>
    <group />
    <device-type>PC2 - UL</device-type>
  </sensor-info>
  <content>
    <elements>
      <element>
        <element-id>2</element-id>
        <element-name>Conf_Lower_Zone</element-name>
        <sensor-type>SINGLE_SENSOR</sensor-type>
        <data-type>ZONE</data-type>
        <from>2017-07-18T15:40:00-04:00</from>
        <to>2017-07-18T15:45:00-04:00</to>
        <resolution>ONE_MINUTE</resolution>
          <measurements>
            <measurement>
              <from>2017-07-18T15:40:00-04:00</from>
              <to>2017-07-18T15:41:00-04:00</to>
              <values>
                <value label="count">0</value>
              </values>
            </measurement>
          <measurement>
              <from>2017-07-18T15:41:00-04:00</from>
              <to>2017-07-18T15:42:00-04:00</to>
               <values>
                  <value label="count">0</value>
               </values>
          </measurement>
```

And Here is my SQL Part:

```
CREATE DATABASE OPENXMLTesting
GO

USE OPENXMLTesting
GO

CREATE TABLE XMLwithOpenXML
(
Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
XMLData XML,
LoadedDateTime DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO XMLwithOpenXML(XMLData, LoadedDateTime)
SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn, GETDATE() 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Example\Test.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;

SELECT * FROM XMLwithOpenXML

USE OPENXMLTesting
GO

DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM XMLwithOpenXML

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

SELECT [element-id], [element-name], [data-type], [ip-address]

FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 
'content/elements/element/measurements/measurement/values/value')

WITH 
(   
    [element-id] varchar (100) '@ElementID',
    [element-name] varchar(50) '@Element_Name',
    [data-type] varchar(50) '@Data_Type',
    [ip-address] varchar(50) '@IP_Address'
)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
GO
```

The problem is that as results i am getting only headers without any data under it. See the pic below. 
[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues...

First of all there is a namespace involved. As it is the *default namespace* you have to declare or wildcard it.

Secondly the chosen approach with `FROM OPENXML` together with the two stored procedures to create and to remove a document is completely outdated. You should use the modern native XML methods. Try this:

```sql
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<response xmlns="http://www.test.com/sensor-api/v2">
  <sensor-time timezone="America/New_York">2017-07-18T15:45:03-04:00</sensor-time>
  <status>
    <code>OK</code>
  </status>
  <sensor-info>
    <serial-number>Q8:80:39:60:9Z:F2</serial-number>
    <ip-address>192.167.130.18</ip-address>
    <name>Test</name>
    <group />
    <device-type>PC2 - UL</device-type>
  </sensor-info>
  <content>
    <elements>
      <element>
        <element-id>2</element-id>
        <element-name>Conf_Lower_Zone</element-name>
        <sensor-type>SINGLE_SENSOR</sensor-type>
        <data-type>ZONE</data-type>
        <from>2017-07-18T15:40:00-04:00</from>
        <to>2017-07-18T15:45:00-04:00</to>
        <resolution>ONE_MINUTE</resolution>
        <measurements>
          <measurement>
            <from>2017-07-18T15:40:00-04:00</from>
            <to>2017-07-18T15:41:00-04:00</to>
            <values>
              <value label="count">0</value>
            </values>
          </measurement>
          <measurement>
            <from>2017-07-18T15:41:00-04:00</from>
            <to>2017-07-18T15:42:00-04:00</to>
            <values>
              <value label="count">0</value>
            </values>
          </measurement>
        </measurements>
      </element>
    </elements>
  </content>
</response>';
```

--The query needs to declare the namespace
--I'll use direct calls to get the singular values
--...and `.nodes()` to get a derived set of `1:n` related elements

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.test.com/sensor-api/v2')
SELECT @xml.value('(/response/sensor-time/@timezone)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS SensortTime_TimeZone
      ,@xml.value('(/response/sensor-time/text())[1]','datetime') AS SensortTime
      ,@xml.value('(/response/status/code/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS StatusCode
      ,@xml.value('(/response/sensor-info/serial-number/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS SerialNumber
      ,e.value('(element-id/text())[1]','int') AS ElementId
      ,e.value('(element-name/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS ElementName
      --more from here
      ,m.value('(from/text())[1]','datetime') AS Measurement_From
      ,m.value('(to/text())[1]','datetime') AS Measurement_To
      ,m.value('(values/value/@label)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Measurement_Label
      ,m.value('(values/value/text())[1]','int') AS Measurement_Label
FROM @xml.nodes('/response/content/elements/element') A(e)
OUTER APPLY e.nodes('measurements/measurement') B(m);
```

Comment: Shnugo- I implement your suggestion however i am still getting the query with only headers and no values at all.

Comment: @Slavisha, With the given example I get data back, so there must be a difference within your XML... Do you see data with the example as given above..

Comment: Shnugo, thank you for helping with all this. Yes you are right,in my example i had just one peace of xml but i was running your mods on entire XML. Which brings me not o another issue, i have to make this load as automated process so whenever XML is dropped in the folder, SQL job will pick it up and append data into table. But that means that I have to somehow automatically edit "DECLARE @xml XML=N' " part to include always entire XML that is placed into folder. Is that even possible to do?

Comment: @Slavisha SQL-Server and T-SQL might be the wrong tool for this. Yes, it is possible, but I'd prefer to do this with a better suited tool like C# or any other language you know. I'd create a windows service, which periodically checks a folder and reads the XML from the disc. You can pass the XML *as is* to a stored procedure and use the approach above to read from it. Or you can use C#'s abilities to get into the XML and pass the naked data. SQL-Server is quite limited in reading from disc (e.g. very limited with encodings...)

Comment: Shnugo, thank you for all your help. I did hours of research on suggestion in your last comment.I was  able to load XML using SSIS package to the Sql Table by using Merge Join process where i connected each element of xml with their keys. The last peace is to add sensor info data by splicing that data with rest of the data and i cant seem to make that work. Do you know which process in SSIS package would give me ability to add Sensor Info data so it repeats for every row for rest of the data? The problem is i dont have unique key between sensor info and rest of the data.

Comment: @Slavisha Please avoid follow-up questions... I'd suggets to start a new question. SSIS is not my daily work and this is rather specific. Place a link to this question, use the appropriate tags, specify tools and versions, place (reduced but realistic) sample data and show what you've done. I'm pretty sure, you'll get answers very soon.